# How to create a jasper report that manage overflow in next page?

Tags: jasper-reports

i would like to know if is possible have a report that has a lot of fields that manage automatically the overflow in other page. I would put every field in `detail` tag and i would like that when there is some element that goes outside of `detail area`, it could be appear in the next one. Below i posted my jasper report:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.0.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.0.0  -->
 <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SvamaTemplate" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="335f8e22-f47d-4b34-abcd-a6682c0cf7b4">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="SvamaTemplateXML"/>
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[/]]>
</queryString>
<field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/@id]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="potenziale_residuo_vpot" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="potenziale_residuo_vpot"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="supporto_rete_sociale" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="supporto_rete_sociale"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="pulizia_casa" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="pulizia_casa"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="lavanderia" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="lavanderia"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="effettuazione_acquisti" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="effettuazione_acquisti"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="bagno" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="bagno"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="toiletta" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="toiletta"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="abbigliamento1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="abbigliamento1"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="uso_wc" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="uso_wc"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="assuzione_medicinali" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="assuzione_medicinali"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="trasferimenti" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="trasferimenti"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="deambulazione1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="deambulazione1"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="gestione_denaro" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="gestione_denaro"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="sostegno_psicoaffettivo" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="sostegno_psicoaffettivo"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="supervisione_diurna" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="supervisione_diurna"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="supervisione_notturna" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/svama/sections/section/subsection/selectOneRadio[@id="supervisione_notturna"]/items/item[@selected="true"]/value/text()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="47" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="230" y="8" width="100" height="30" uuid="91c6fde2-503f-4228-8cf0-e2878b9fdb3b"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="20" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[SVAMA]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="13" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="13" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="270" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="130" y="120" width="424" height="30" uuid="74e0b517-f4c9-4679-a8d2-54e7f4582a3e"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pulizia_casa}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="10" y="120" width="110" height="30" uuid="40f82bd5-9d95-45b3-b21d-c7f738c576c5"/>
            <text><![CDATA[pulizia_casa]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="130" y="200" width="424" height="30" uuid="f8c91c60-26bb-419e-87a7-8b2dd158b83b"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{effettuazione_acquisti}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="10" y="200" width="110" height="30" uuid="e2d4b4b2-5c98-4041-9b94-36aa7e2c53e5"/>
            <text><![CDATA[effettuazione_acquisti]]></text>
        </staticText>
<!-- break is attempt, i don't know what should put here -->
        <break>
            <reportElement x="0" y="270" width="517" height="1" uuid="08ff5b1a-7ff4-4848-ba95-e9ce31d0d44e"/>
        </break>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="10" y="280" width="110" height="30" uuid="e2d4b4b2-5c98-4041-9b94-36aa7e2c53e5"/>
            <text><![CDATA[toiletta]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="130" y="280" width="424" height="30" uuid="f8c91c60-26bb-419e-87a7-8b2dd158b83b"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{toiletta}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="10" y="320" width="110" height="30" uuid="e2d4b4b2-5c98-4041-9b94-36aa7e2c53e5"/>
            <text><![CDATA[abbigliamento1]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="130" y="320" width="424" height="30" uuid="f8c91c60-26bb-419e-87a7-8b2dd158b83b"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{abbigliamento1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="10" y="360" width="110" height="30" uuid="e2d4b4b2-5c98-4041-9b94-36aa7e2c53e5"/>
            <text><![CDATA[uso_wc]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="130" y="360" width="424" height="30" uuid="f8c91c60-26bb-419e-87a7-8b2dd158b83b"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{uso_wc}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="10" y="440" width="110" height="30" uuid="e2d4b4b2-5c98-4041-9b94-36aa7e2c53e5"/>
            <text><![CDATA[trasferimenti]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="130" y="440" width="424" height="30" uuid="f8c91c60-26bb-419e-87a7-8b2dd158b83b"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{trasferimenti}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="10" y="520" width="110" height="30" uuid="e2d4b4b2-5c98-4041-9b94-36aa7e2c53e5"/>
            <text><![CDATA[gestione_denaro]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="130" y="520" width="424" height="30" uuid="f8c91c60-26bb-419e-87a7-8b2dd158b83b"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{gestione_denaro}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="10" y="560" width="110" height="30" uuid="e2d4b4b2-5c98-4041-9b94-36aa7e2c53e5"/>
            <text><![CDATA[sostegno_psicoaffettivo]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="130" y="560" width="424" height="30" uuid="f8c91c60-26bb-419e-87a7-8b2dd158b83b"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sostegno_psicoaffettivo}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="10" y="640" width="110" height="30" uuid="e2d4b4b2-5c98-4041-9b94-36aa7e2c53e5"/>
            <text><![CDATA[supervisione_notturna]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="130" y="640" width="424" height="30" uuid="f8c91c60-26bb-419e-87a7-8b2dd158b83b"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{supervisione_notturna}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

`<detail>
    <band height="270" splitType="Stretch">`

to

```
<detail>
    <band height="270" splitType="Immediate">
```

In case it starts printing a blank page at the end, you might want to use:

```
<detail>
    <band height="270" splitType="Prevent">
```

Instead

Comment: The problem is that band has a fixed height and I don't know how to place exceed element.  I got this warning : Element bottom reaches outside band area : y=440 height=30 band-height=440. Is there a way to set a relative position to each element? I saw the property 'RelativeToTallestObject' but i don't know how it works.